# Java String comparison fails within KeyListener

Tags: java, string, swing, keylistener

I am having an incredibly frustrating time trying to figure out why a KeyListener wont fully execute. It must be something in Java of which I am just unaware.

I'm trying to use a KeyListener to catch the user entering text into a JTextArea via the "Enter" Key. When the user presses Enter, the String they entered into the JTextArea is saved via `.getText();` and is then compared to another String to see if they match using `.equalsIgnoreCase();`, but the program seems to completely ignore this batch of code. I've been trying to find my error on and off for 3 days now and can't think of anything.

Below is the example of my code. In this example, I'm trying to get the program to execute `System.exit(0);` in the event the user types the word "quit". Any help is appreciated. I'm really hoping I didn't just forget something stupid.

```
playerInput.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    String test = playerInput.getText();
                    String quit = "quit";
                    playerInput.setText("");
                    if(test.equalsIgnoreCase(quit))
                        System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
        });
```

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger?  What is "test" coming back as?

Comment: Could you try with `String test = playerInput.getText().trim();`

Comment: Can you put a `println` statement at the beginning of the `keyReleased` method to ensure that the method is actually getting called? If it isn't, my bet would be that you're having an issue with the [Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html).

Comment: @ametren The debugger returns test as null, which is definitely the source of my problem.

Comment: In that case, I'm actually surprised that you're not getting a NullPointerException on test.equalsIgnoreCase(quit)

Comment: KeyListener isn't designated for Swing GUI, use KeyBindings instead, but correct answer is by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels,

Comment: Thanks for the advice @mKorbel and Hovercraft Full of Eels. I will definitely adopt this practice in the long run. I was unaware of the KeyListener and SwingGUI conflicts.

Comment: @Speakr there no significant conflict(s), but you'll be Focus & Focusable hunter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
playerInput.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    String test = playerInput.getText().replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
                    String quit = "quit";
                    playerInput.setText("");
                    if(test.equalsIgnoreCase(quit))
                        System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
        });
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. I'm guessing that I was inserting a newline without realizing it. Although it doesn't explain why the debugger returns 'test' as null.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a DocumentListener and check in it if the text held by the document contains the word "quit".

Comment: This is a great idea/response. I only chose the other one because it didn't require a large reworking of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the user typing "quit" or "quit\n\r" ... if you get my drift. Perhaps there is extra whitespace in the `JTextArea`.

Try `test.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(quit)`